# Advanced wraps in CSS

Tags: css, line-breaks, word-wrap

I have the following code:

```
<time>2018-23-12&nbsp;23:59</time> — <time>2018-24-12&nbsp;23:59</time>
```

The problem is that dash.
When the second time tag is breaking into a new line, the dash should break into an extra line. When no break is needed, then the text should be as it is.

So the output behaviour, what I am trying to force is:

```
<time>2018-23-12&nbsp;23:59</time>
—
<time>2018-24-12&nbsp;23:59</time>
```

Any ideas how to solve that?
Thanks for your help everybody :-)

Comment: You want each `<time>` element to render in a new line?

Comment: yes, but only when the container was not big enough to hold the complete code in the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
time,
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<time>2018-23-12&nbsp;23:59</time> <span>—</span> <time>2018-24-12&nbsp;23:59</time>
```

Something like this ?

Comment: sadly no. it is now possible that the dash is on the same line as the first time tag. the dash should be in a extra line, when the second time is breaking to a new line becauseof missing space in the container

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to do that without using breakpoint. If you need I can help you with breakpoint

Comment: Okay I am using now breakpoints. thanks for the help. Sadly there is no solution for the descriped way. But with breakpoints it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`display:block;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) to `time`

```css
time{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<time>2018-23-12&nbsp;23:59</time> — <time>2018-24-12&nbsp;23:59</time>
```

Comment: tell me for more help:)

Comment: thanks, but this does not resolve the issue. When the browser window is big enough, then the time blocks should not wrap and the dash should show up in the same line. The dash should only wrap to a special line, when the second time is wrapped to another line. I don't want to use breakpoints here

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("section").resizable();
```

```css
section{
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-height: 80px;
}

time{
  display:inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<section>
  <time>2018-23-12&nbsp;23:59</time>
  &ndash;
  <time>2018-24-12&nbsp;23:59</time>
</section>
```

If you want the `-` to break into a line of its own, you might need some javascript to detect a line break and change the HTML accordingly